# How to set permissions on an angular page

Tags: permissions, angular

I have developed a basic angular page and forms which stores data in the database. However the data stored are settings and should only be accesible when a user has a permission for Administer CiviCRM.

How do I that? I don't have a Menu.xml where I would usually do that but I do have routing options in the angular controller.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks for posting the comment. I found indeed a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this. The developer docs (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/angular/loader/) mention how you could create your own angular page, which is a regular civicrm page but at a different url.

Because it is a regular page I could set permissions for that just as I was used to do. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/routing/#access_arguments for how to do that.